# Разбить датафрейм Pandas на два датафрейма по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Мне нужно разбить датафрейм Pandas на два датафрейма по условию.

Понятно, что можно сделать просто две выборки из исходного датафрейма по противоположным условиям. Но здесь получается два прохода по одним и тем же данным. Есть ли какое-то более прямое решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
In [66]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(-1,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [67]: df
Out[67]:
    a   b   c
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
5  15  16  17
6  18  19  20
7  21  22  23
8  24  25  26
9  27  28  29
```

Получаем "boolean mask" по условию:

```
In [68]: mask = df['a'] % 2 == 0

In [69]: mask
Out[69]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8     True
9    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

фильтруем по "boolean mask" - это очень быстрая операция (называется - [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)):

```
In [70]: df1, df2 = df[mask], df[~mask]

In [71]: df1
Out[71]:
    a   b   c
0   0   1   2
2   6   7   8
4  12  13  14
6  18  19  20
8  24  25  26

In [72]: df2
Out[72]:
    a   b   c
1   3   4   5
3   9  10  11
5  15  16  17
7  21  22  23
9  27  28  29
```

**Замер времени для DF состоящего из 10.000.000 строк**:

```
In [78]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10**6, size=(10**7,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [79]: df.shape
Out[79]: (10000000, 3)

In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: mask = df['a'] % 3 == 0
    ...: df1, df2 = df[mask], df[~mask]
    ...:
342 ms ± 4.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```